# An extension problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ for $n \geq 2$, and $p \in \Omega$.

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $f: \Omega \setminus \{p\} \to \mathbb R$ is in $C^k$, and $\lim_{x \to p} D^k f (x)$ exists.

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ admits an extension to $\Omega$ that is in $C^k (\Omega)$?

Comment: ? $k=n=1$, $p=0$, $f(x)=0 (x>0)$ $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Ah sorry, $n \geq 2$.

Comment: It looks like the limits of derivatives of order less than $k$ exist (by backward induction, and Cauchy criterion), this allows to define $f(p) $, and the derivatives at $p$ of $f$, what may go wrong?

Comment: Ahh yes, this does follow from the $k = 1$ case quite easily... I missed the obvious induction procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}$This is to detail the [comment by Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446053/an-extension-problem#comment1152071_446053).

Without loss of generality, $p=0$ and $\Om$ is an open ball in $\R^n$ centered at $p=0$. Assume, slightly more generally, that $f\colon\Om_0\to\R^d$ for some natural $d$, where $\Om_0:=\Om\setminus\{0\}$. (Actually, the original problem is clearly equivalent to the "$d$-dimensional" one.) Let $g\colon\Om_0\to\R$ denote any coordinate-function of the vector function $f$.
Let $L^kf:=\lim_{x\to0}(D^kf)(x)\in((\R^n)')^d$ and $L^kg:=\lim_{x\to0}(D^kg)(x)\in(\R^n)'$, where $(\R^n)'$ is the space of all linear functionals on $\R^n$; let us identify $(\R^n)'$ with $\R^n$ in the standard manner, and then $((\R^n)')^d$ with $\R^{nd}$.

Consider first the case $k=1$. Take any sequence $(x_r)$ in $\Om_0$ such that $x_r\to0$ and $0$ is not on the straight line segment $[x_m,x_r]$ from $x_m$ to $x_r$ for any natural $m,r$; let us call such a sequence $(x_r)$ *good*. Then, by the mean value theorem, for any (coordinate-function) $g$, any natural $m$ and $r$, and some $t_{m,r}\in(0,1)$ we have
\begin{equation}
    g(x_r)-g(x_m)=(D^1g)(x_m+t_{m,r}(x_r-x_m))(x_r-x_m)\to0
\end{equation}
as $m,r\to\infty$, since $x_r-x_m\to0$, $x_m+t_{m,r}(x_r-x_m)\to0$, and hence $(D^1g)(x_m+t_{m,r}(x_r-x_m))\to L^1g\in(\R^n)'=\R^n$. So, by the Cauchy convergence test, the sequence $(g(x_r))$ converges to a limit in $\R$ and hence the sequence $(f(x_r))$ converges to a limit in $\R^d$.

Now take any sequence $(x_r)$ in $\Om_0$ such that $x_r\to0$, now allowing $0$ to be on the straight line segment $[x_m,x_r]$ for some natural $m,r$. We can consecutively approximate the sequence $(x_r)$ by a good sequence $(y_r)$ such that $|x_r-y_r|+|f(x_r)-f(y_r)|<1/r$ for all natural $r$ -- **it is only here that we use the condition $n\ge2$** (here we also use the continuity of $f$ on $\Om_0$). So, for any sequence $(x_r)$ in $\Om_0$ such that $x_r\to0$, the sequence $(f(x_r))$ converges to a limit in $\R^d$. Clearly, this limit, which let us denote by $f(0)$, does not depend on the choice of a sequence $(x_r)$ in $\Om_0$ such that $x_r\to0$, so that $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$. Let then $g(0):=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$.

Moreover, using the mean value theorem again (as well as the condition $L^kg:=\lim_{x\to0}(D^kg)(x)$), for all $x\in\Om_0$ and some $t_x\in(0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
    g(x)-g(0)-(L^1g)(x)=(D^1g)(t_x x)(x)-(L^1g)(x)=((D^1g)(t_x x)-L^1g)(x)=o(|x|)
\end{equation}
as $x\to0$, where $|x|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of $x$. Thus, $(D^1g)(0)=L^1g$ and hence $(D^1f)(0)=L^1f$.

So, the case $k=1$ is done. The general case of any natural $k$ now follows by backward induction, utilizing the vector extension of the original problem and identifying the arising  finite-dimensional linear spaces of linear functionals with spaces $\R^N$ of appropriate dimensions $N$.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer, and the highlighting of where $n \geq 2$ is used.

Answer (score 2):

(Comment: The only solution can be the continuous extension, right. If you restrict to a line $L$ in $\Omega$ containing $p$, extend $D^k f$ continuously on $L$, integrate it $k$-fold on $L$, you have a solution $F_L$ on $L$. This appears to be the continuous extension of $f$ on $L$. Since this goes with every $L$, $f$ can be continuously extended, and so the solution is independent of $L$.)

Comment: You cannot just deal with lines through $p$. Cf. the example $f(x)=1(x>0)$ in the comment by [terceira](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446053/an-extension-problem#comment1152063_446053) for the case when the dimension $n$ is $1$. You need to use the condition $n\ge2$, which does not seem to play a role in your answer.

Comment: If there were to be chosen different integration constants for the halflines seperated by p to get continuous extension, then f could not be continuous around p (connectedness of $\Omega - p$). Here is $n >1$

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "integration constants" and how exactly you can use the connectedness. Also, behavior along the rays does not by itself ensure the desired behavior in an entire neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: You take curves instead of lines, for example along a prescribed sequence converging to p

Comment: OK, now "curves instead of lines, for example along a prescribed sequence converging to p" ...  What curves exactly? And why do you need them at all, in addition to "a prescribed sequence converging to p"? After all that curving-decurving is done, will the resulting proof substantially differ from the one in my answer?